# Using VBS script SendKeys to activate hotkeys through Task Scheduler

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I have Open Broadcaster Software installed and I want to use it to automatically record the desktop at scheduled times. In OBS, I've set up a "start record" hotkey (in this cast ALT 1) and a "stop record" hotkey (ALT 2).

OBS starts with Windows and opens minimized to the task bar.

Pressing the hotkeys keys successfully starts and stops screen recordings regardless of what program is open or focused on.

I want to be able to use Task Scheduler to schedule recordings at specific times throughout the week. Task Scheduler cannot schedule key strokes so I created a start.vbs file and a stop.vbs file. Here's where my problem is, I can't figure out how to get the 'ALT 1' or 'ALT 2' keys to be recognized by OBS.

Here's what I have for my start.vbs:

```
'Start Recording
Option Explicit
Dim WSHShell, strDesktop
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
WSHShell.AppActivate strDesktop
WSHShell.SendKeys "%1"
WScript.Quit
```

It seems to run fine, but the keystrokes don't register. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like my code is fine and it's the particular program I'm running that doesn't register the keystrokes...?